# App is closed when I press back button from local gallery in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am on Activity and there, I call Local storage gallery.

```
  fun selectGallery() {
            val readPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            )

            // 권한 확인
            if (readPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                // 권한 요청
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    arrayOf(
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                    ),
                    100
                )
            } else {

                var intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
                intent.data = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                intent.type = "image/*"

                startActivityForResult(intent, 2000)
            }
        }


        binding.editAvatar.setOnClickListener {
            selectGallery()
        }


 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        when (requestCode) {
   
            2000 -> {
                // 사진 가져오기
                selectedAvatarURI = data?.data!!

                Glide.with(this)
                    .load(selectedAvatarURI)
                    .into(binding.avatarImage)

                editFillClass.avatarFill.value = true

            }
        }
    }
```

So This code works well.

When I click one button, local gallery screen is opened.

But there, if I press back button, app is killed.

Strange thing is same code is used in another `Fragment`.

There, app is not closed even if I press back button.

It goes to previous fragment page.

Why does it happen and How can I make just gallery screen is closed when I press back button?

Comment: First of all add stacktrace from logcat. It will be very helpful. My guess - it is because  of "data?.data!!", but show the logs first

Comment: @researcher yes you were correct, it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the result, the most likely the `data` is null:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        when (requestCode) {
   
            2000 -> {
                // 사진 가져오기
                selectedAvatarURI = data?.data
                if (selectedAvatarURI != null) {
                    Glide.with(this)
                        .load(selectedAvatarURI)
                        .into(binding.avatarImage)

                    editFillClass.avatarFill.value = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
```